# drop hive table partition through pig script

Tags: hive, apache-pig

Currently we are dropping the table daily and running the script which loads the data to the tables. Script takes 3-4 hrs during which data will not be available. So now our aim is to make the old hive data available to analysts until new data load execution is complete.

I am achieving this thing in hql script by loading daily data to the hive tables partitioned on load_year, load_month and load_day and dropping the yesterdays data by dropping the partition. 
But what is the option for pig script to achieve the same? Can we alter the table through pig script? I dont want to execute the other hql to drop partition after pig.
Thanks

Comment: Pig is used for data flow ... so while picking data for process pic correct data...

Comment: I am sorry. I didn't get you. My question is not related to picking up data, it is related to storing the data in pig and after storing dropping the old data through pig.

Answer (score 0):

Since HDP 2.3 you can use HCatalog commands inside Pig scripts. Therefore, you can use the HCatalog command to drop a Hive table partition. The following is an example of dropping a Hive partition:

```
-- Set the correct hcat path 
set hcat.bin /usr/bin/hcat;
-- Drop a table partion or execute other any Hcatalog command
sql ALTER TABLE midb1.mitable1 DROP IF EXISTS PARTITION(activity_id = "VENTA_ALIMENTACION",transaction_month = 1);
```

Another way is to use sh command execution inside Pig Script. However I had some problems to escape special characters in ALTER commands. So, the first is the best option in my opinion.

Regards,
Roberto Tardío